# React - List Items props doesn't pass into rendered List component

Tags: list, reactjs, components, listitem

I'm new at React Js, I tried to make a List component to inject different ListItems.
But when items passed, props doesn't pass.
What went wrong?

**Update 12Mar,2017**

```js
const List = (props) => {
  const ComponentToRender = props.component;
  let content = (<div></div>);

  if (props.items) {
    content = props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <ComponentToRender key={`item-${index}`} item={item}/>
    ));
  } else {
    content = (<ComponentToRender />);
  }

  return (
      <ul>
        {content}
      </ul>
  ); 
}

const ListItem = (props) => ( 
    <li>
       <a href={props.href}>
         <i className={props.icon}></i>
         {props.name}
      </a>
    </li>
);

const el = [
  {href: "#", icon: "fa fa-phone", name: "bannana"},
  {href: "#", icon: "fa fa-phone", name: "apples"}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <List component={ListItem} items={el} />
  </div>
  ,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[See on codepen](http://codepen.io/viiiprock/pen/vxOgmr?editors=0010)

Thanks in advance my friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `items` as `item`:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <List component={ListItem1} items={["banana", "apples"]} />
    <List component={ListItem1} items={["banana", "apples"]} />
  </div>
  ,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Hi Ming Soon,
would you mind to help me to know why the props don't pass such as name, icon, href...
http://codepen.io/viiiprock/pen/vxOgmr?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Alright I find it myself
just pass:

```
<ComponentToRender key={`item-${index}`} {...item}/>
```